# Postgres 9.4 how can i do a max constraint on an int field

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4

I am new to postgres and have been trying to find a way to put a max limit on a Field. I have a field in the database named **friends** and it is of type **INT** I want to put a constraint on that field of 30 so that no number saved in that field could be higher than 30. I am using postgres 9.4 and PgAdmin 3 . I am reading this page http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-set-constraints.html but can not find anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `CHECK` constraint for that.

When creating the schema, just type:

```
CREATE TABLE sometable (
  ...
  friends int CONSTRAINT high_friends CHECK (friends <= 30)
)
```

Comment: OP *probably* needs `friends between 0 and 30`.